# fill nan with "ND" if before the nan there is a value

Tags: fillna

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    A    B    C
1   32  nan   nan
2   32  nan   nan
3  nan  nan   14
4  nan  nan   nan
```

my desired output is the following:

```
    A    B    C
1   32  nan   nan
2   32  nan   nan
3   ND  nan   14
4   ND  nan   ND
```

Basically, I need:

1. To exclude all the columns with only nan values
2. To fill nan (with "ND") after a value and not before! (see column C)

Could you help me, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution:

```
df=df.where(df.ffill().isna(), df.fillna("ND"))
```

However, if you try to run this line you will get the following error:

TypeError: <U2 cannot be converted to an IntegerDtype

I solved it using replace:

```
df=df.where(df.ffill().isna(), df.fillna(123456789123456789))
df= df.replace(123456789123456789, "ND")
```